# Windows 7 Root Folder appears empty

Tags: windows-7

I have a Dell Inspiron #580 running Windows 7 Home Premium.  The special 'numbered' file that the shortcut to my Root directory is gone and when I navigate to the Root directory it appears empty! Please tell me how I can fix this.

**Update:**
It's now about four hours later and i have decided to byte the bullet and restore to an earlier state. Thanks again! I have noticed that when I do a restore it COMPLETELY restores not only removing the problem, malware, etc. but also removing all improvements i have made requiring me to redo them. So before restoring this time I copied my desktop folder and my Icons folder to a flash drive which I then unplugged. I have yet to plug it back in and see what I was able to save. I hope that this info is somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Could they be hidden?

**Tools** > **Folder Options** > **View** > Show Hidden Files and Folders